# Wordpress custom fields to show Link with URL

Tags: wordpress

I have slider which show images, excerpt, and link for each slides. I was able to add images and excerpt from the post. I need to show a link to detailed page as  url link on the slide to page "Visit Online store". How can I add a custom field where I can give URL title and URL and that can be shown on the slider. I tried to give the link  as HTML but is it not displaying when I show excerpt. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following plugin. Hope this will help you.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshow-satellite/installation/